# Not able to push docker image into untrusted registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry, harbor

I have configured Harbor docker registry in GCP compute engine (hostname : harbor ) , as I have not installed any certificate I am able to access the registry through http (port 80) & from client end (within same VPC of harbor registry compute engine) I have configured docker insecure registry as below

```
[root@client docker]# cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
"insecure-registries" : [
    "harbor:80",
    "<external-ip>:80",
    "10.128.0.20:80"
  ],
  "debug" : true,
  "experimental" : true
}
```

but while I am trying to login into the docker registry I am getting bellow error (it's automatically hitting my registry in port 443 not 80)

```
[root@client docker]# docker login -u "####" -p "####" harbor 

Error response from daemon: Get https://harbor/v1/users/: dial tcp 10.128.0.20:443: connect: connection refused
```

Could you please help me resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to pick the wrong port, 443. Try adding a port explicitly: `docker login -u "####" -p "####" harbor:80`. Note I strongly recommend against using authentication over unencrypted channels (HTTP vs HTTPS). Perhaps `docker login` is smart enough to refuse to do it.

Comment: Thanks it's working for me , actually I am working on test environment , so not installed CA certified certificate yet . Thanks again